# Prove that $Range(S)$ is invariant under $T$ when $TS=ST$ ($T,S \in L(V)$)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I was trying to solve this problem but stuck with the following reasoning:

Suppose $S$ is the identity operator under a vector space $V$ (e.g. under $\mathbb{R}^1$). Let's then $T$ be such an operator that $Tv \mapsto 0v$. Then for any vector we have the equality being hold because $T(Sv) = T(v) = 0 = S(0) = S(Tv)$, so $TS=ST$. But then, e.g. for $v=5$ we have that $v \in Range(S)$ and $Tv \in Null(S)$. Therefore, the assertion is not always hold.

Could you please help me to understand where I'm gone wrong? Thank you!

Comment: It's quite famous problem and it was asked a few times here (and proved to be true). Though I don't want to see any spoilers..

Comment: Note that this question does not actually have anything to do with linear algebra. This is true for arbitrary functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**what went wrong with your counterexample**
You pick $S$ the identity operator, $T$ the zero-operator. You're proof why $TS = ST$ is correct.

You then proceed to take $v = 5 \in \mathbb{R}$. You have that $5 \in \operatorname{Range}(S)$ since $S(5) = 5$.

Then you make you're mistake: you state (correctly) that $T(5) = 0 \notin \operatorname{Range}(S)$. This is **not true!**.

The range of an operator is a vectorspace, hence it always contains $0$.

**How to prove this statement (which is correct)**

What you need to show is that $$T(\operatorname{Range}(S)) = \operatorname{Range}(S)$$
In order to do this, you try to prove two inclusions: the left hand side is included in the right hand side and vice versa.

1. Start with an element $v \in \operatorname{Range}(S)$.
2. What can you tell about $v$? What can you tell about $T(v)$?
3. Your ultimate goal is to show that $T(v) \in \operatorname{Range}(S)$, what do you need to prove in order for $T(v)$ to be an element of $\operatorname{Range}(S)$?

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. You are saying I am proving it from the wrong door, but is not my reasoning is a counter example?

Comment: @mur_tm I misread your question. You try to give a counterexample of the statement. You did this mostly correct, but went wrong in your last step. See my edited answer for details!

Comment: Yes, I understood my flaw, thank you so much! I did not understood that, in case of considering an operator, $Ker$ and $Im$ will always have $\{0\}$ in their intersection and it agrees with their definitions.